# new limit within php: 1000 fields per POST. Does someone know, if the number can be influenced?

Tags: php, post

In newer PHP-Versions the count of input-fileds per formula (POST) will be limited to 1000 (unverified information). It seams that this limit is already installed in certain builds of 5.2. This causes a lot of problems at our online shop.

Does someone know more about it and if this limit could be influenced by parameters or Vars.
I just found max_input_vars, but it seems to be a complete new var of 5.4.RC4 And I'm not sure, if this var will be the one for the POST method.

Comment: I'd suggest you shouldn't have that many fields in a single form anyway... if you have, then you should probably reconsider how your pages are structured and use sessions.

Comment: It's a `php.ini` setting, and it can only be set [in the `php.ini`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/php.ini-production?view=markup&pathrev=321040#l460) as it's required prior runtime initialization.

Comment: Mark and Mario are right, but you can also `Stringify` (Google it) your fields and pass them as one field.

Comment: You should probably not be judging about how much is too much for a certain application. I mean we're in 21-st century. I guess a form with 1000 fields isn't really sooo much.

Comment: @Slavic - I'd suggest that 1000 fields on a form is a bad user-experience if they're user-accessible fields, and if they're hidden fields then there's better ways of handling data in forms (such as sessions). About the only exception I can think of would be Google spreadsheet.

Comment: The problem occures in a variant of xtCommerce, so its a kind of standard software. Peter

Comment: @mario i set max_input_vars to 5000 to make it work. But I got an Internal Server Error, don't know why. Tested on a shared hosting packet, so I can't see the servers error logs.

Comment: Ask your hosting provider about the logs.

Comment: @MarkBaker Maybe it is some sort of webservice, too.

Comment: Saying this is bad user-experience is an invalid claim in many cases these days. Venturing to guess @MarkBaker does not deal with many ecommerce applications that have multiple languages or many options/attributes per product. Hitting the 1000 field limit is well within reason under those circumstances :P

Comment: @RobertM You can guess as much as you like..... if a user is actually faced with that many fields on a screen, they'll likely abandon it.... if they're hidden fields, then there's likely a better way that the application could have been designed.... precisely as I said.... just because an ecommerce app can create 1000+ fields for multiple options/attributes for multiple basket items doesn't mean that it's good design

Comment: @MarkBaker Maybe I should clarify this is perfectly reasonable in an admin area, not on the front-end for regular users :P

If you ever worked in a system where there were enough fields to hit the cap which were perfectly justifiable I doubt there would have been a retort ;)

Most ecommerce system admin areas can hit a 1000 field limit with ease for complex products with multiple languages while still following good design and usability practices. It's this little thing called interface tabs :D

Comment: @MarkBaker There are plenty of scenarios where a 1000 input form is legit and not a bad user experience.  Consider an editable list.  If each row has even just 4 or 5 editable fields plus a bunch of hidden inputs, you can easily have several thousand inputs in your form, when you have hundreds of rows. 
 Especially if you have multiple lists, each in their own UI tab, but all part of the same form.

Answer (score 66):

[max_input_vars](https://www.php.net/manual/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

is an attempt for PHP to solve some security issues and when set, it limits your number of inputs (thus, fields in your forms). Also beware of

[max_input_nesting_level](https://www.php.net/manual/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level)

And yes - they are configurable. Just edit your php.ini or htaccess values.

Comment: Two more to watch out for are `suhosin.post.max_vars` and `suhosin.request.max_vars`

Comment: Default values I had with php 5.3.43 `php -i | grep max_input_vars`: `max_input_vars => 1000 => 1000`
`php -i | grep max_input_nesting_level `: `max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64`

Comment: @GabLeRoux Note that lines above will print out the value even if it's commented out with `;`

Answer (score 34):

I too have come across this issue, working on a localised installation of my code, and Debian Sid has upgraded to 5.4 RC4 PHP. A form of over 7000 lines with checkboxes (!) suddenly only processed 1001 of these in the $_POST data...head scratching for a few hours.

Made the change in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
max_input_vars = 5000
```

save, and restart apache, and it's all good now.

Answer (score 7):

If you cannot/ do not want to increase the server limit, here is another solution

```
<!-- 10000 checkboxes outside the FORM. You do not want to post this -->
<input class="cbox" type="checkbox" value="1"  id="id-1" checked name="id[]">
....
<input class="cbox" type="checkbox" value="10000"  id="id-10000" checked name="id[]">
<form method="POST" action="postpage.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="cboxes" name="cboxes" class="cboxes" value="" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();">
</form>
```

then using jquery

```
<script>
function clicked() {
    var cb = $('.cbox:checked').map(function() {return this.value;}).get().join(',');
    $('#cboxes').val(cb);
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Using POST I tested posting 10000 records.

In the server

```
$cboxes = $_POST['cboxes'];
$cbox_exp =(explode(',', $cboxes));
print_r(count($cbox_exp)); //gives me 10000
```

Comment: Should mention the requirement of jquery in your example or change it to use straight javascript ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to summarize and point out a few things:

1) Limitations can be PHP as mentioned above.

2) Limitations can be web server also mentioned above.

3) **Suhosin** limitations only apply if it is installed. Settings are changed in php.ini

4) Beware of browser URL length limits if you attempt to submit that much data in the URL

Restart your web server after changing any server settings.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it looks like a patch on linux environment causing this issue. If your server has this patch 'suhosin', likely to be the issue. Also its not possible to override this in runtime rather include in your `php.ini`

```
suhosin.post.max_array_depth 

suhosin.post.max_array_index_length 

suhosin.post.max_name_length 

suhosin.post.max_totalname_length 

suhosin.post.max_vars 

suhosin.post.max_value_length
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always good to just stringify some of the data you're submitting – rather than change this limit within PHP. For example, if you're sending in stuff via Ajax, or via a form field, just stringify the field that's causing the problem.

The limit is on the 'number' of fields and not the 'length', if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

These changes tend to be well documented. Are you sure that it's been backported to 5.2? Where did you read so? It seems more likely that you are hitting some other limit such as [post_max_size](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) or Apache's [LimitRequestFields](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#limitrequestfields), or even a PHP security mod like [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/).

(Furthermore, PHP 5.2 is no longer supported, so I doubt it'd receive such upgrade.)

Comment: Our provider has 5.2.17 on its servers. It is a new build from 12-/29/2011. And there in phpinfo I can read max-input-vars ist set to 1000. This is the limit I fight with. I'm shure about it.

Comment: Out provider is one of the biggest in germany, perhaps he uses some extentions like Suhosin or parts of it. Suhosin itself - I have no information, that they use it.

Comment: PHP 5.2.17 was released one year ago. If you actually have `max_input_vars` available, your big German provider compiled a non-official PHP source code tarball.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Dreamhost like me you can create a phprc file inside `/home/<<siteuser>>/.php/<<X.Y>>` (siteuser = the user your site runs under, and X.Y = php version eg 7.2)

Inside the phprc I added `max_input_vars = 2000`

You must then kill all the PHP processes to take effect using `killall -9 php72.cgi`if you were on PHP version 7.2

More info here https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/214200668-How-do-I-create-a-phprc-file-via-SSH-

Answer (score -1):

If you do not use multiple or more than 1000 input fields
you can be concatenating multiple inputs with any special character, for example `@`

```
<input type='text' name='hs1' id='hs1'>
<input type='text' name='hs2' id='hs2'>
<input type='text' name='hs3' id='hs3'>
<input type='text' name='hs4' id='hs4'>
<input type='text' name='hs5' id='hs5'>

<input type='hidden' name='hd' id='hd'>
```

using any script (JavaScript or JScript)

```
document.getElementById("hd").value =     document.getElementById("hs1").value+"@"+document.getElementById("hs2").value+"@"+document.getElementById("hs3").value+"@"+document.getElementById("hs4").value+"@"+document.getElementById("hs5").value
```

with this concept you will be bypass the `max_input_vars` issue.
    If you increase the `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` file that is harmful to server.
    Because they use more server cache memory and sometimes they will crash the server.