# php POST data doesn't contain all elements, despite the fact that post_max_size is big enough

Tags: php, post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [new limit within php: 1000 fields per POST. Does someone know, if the number can be influenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can)

My form contains huge set of text inputs. Last ones of them doesn't appear in `$_POST` array.
I encreased `post_max_size` and `upload_max_size` to `128M`, but it doesn't help.
Size fo my post data doesn't exeed that limit.

---

Form contains `1001` items like `<input type="text" name="field_name[]"/>`  and there's no anything after that array in my $_POST.

---

This problem appears only on my development server (ubuntu server 12.10), it works good on my linux Mint 13. There's allmost nothing edited in default php.ini files on both machines.

Comment: This will probably answer your question: [new limit within php: 1000 fields per POST. Does someone know, if the number can be influenced?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can)

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but you might consider using something like Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the request being sent by your browser. It will at least indicate whether the browser is sending the full request.

Comment: +1 to jeroen, and don't forget that even if PHP's limits are raised, the webserver and/or whatever security systems are within the webserver (e.g. suhosin) can impose their own limits that kick in long before PHP ever gets involved with the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing [max_input_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars) - that limits the size of the $_POST array.