# JSON.stringify comes back empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to json serialize an array as follows:

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
  (function ($) {

    var contact, name, email, entry;
    var emails = [];
    var post_object = {};    

    for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
      contact = contacts[i];
      emails[i] = {};
      emails[i]['name'] = contact.fullName();
      emails[i]['email'] = contact.selectedEmail();
      console.log(contacts.length)
    }

    post_object['emails']=emails;
    post_object['source']=source;
    post_object['owner']=owner;

    $.post("/cloudsponge-post",JSON.stringify(post_object),function(data) {

    window.location.href = "/after-import";

    });
  }(jQuery));
}
```

The problem is, the post comes back empty. Without JSON.stringify() I get all the elements (but there are thousands of them, which can hit some servers limits, so they need to be serialized). Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't think we can do anything without server side code

Comment: did you tried to log `JSON.stringify(post_object)` ?

Comment: the relevant server side code is <?php print_r($_POST); ?>. The problem is definitely from stringify.

Comment: So the problem is that `$_POST` is empty on the server?

Comment: Yes. JSON.stringify(post_object) works as expected, but the resultant $_POST is empty.

Comment: Perhaps $.post sends the object as form encoded data, but treats the string as the actual body, and your php is not looking for a JSON body?

Comment: Where are you even getting this much client-side data? Is this a mobile device contact scraper?

Comment: No, it allows you to import your address book from gmail/hotmail etc to Drupal. It's an integration using the third party service 'cloudsponge', which lets you post back the data via javascript. In my case, I have >3000 contacts in my address book, so it chokes it at 1000 fields, hence the need to serialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was this. When the request to the server is of type JSON, it's not strictly a POST, so PHP does not populate the $_POST field. In order to retrieve the data, it must be read directly from the request, in other words, instead of using $_POST, use:

```
$data=file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to call `JSON.stringify`, $.post accepts an object, check [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Code to post just a few emails at a time :

```
function postToDrupal(contacts, source, owner) {
    var pending = 0, limit = 10;
    var post_patch = function(emails) {
        var post_object = {};
        post_object['emails']=emails;
        post_object['source']=source;
        post_object['owner']=owner;
        pending++;
        $.post("/cloudsponge-post", post_object,function(data) {
            if(pending-- == 0) {
                window.location.href = "/after-import";
            }
        });
    }
    (function ($) {

        var contact, emails = [];   

        for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
            contact = contacts[i];
            emails[i] = {};
            emails[i]['name'] = contact.fullName();
            emails[i]['email'] = contact.selectedEmail();
            console.log(contacts.length)
            if(limit-- == 0) {
                limit = 10
                post_patch(emails);
                contact = null; emails = {};
            }
        }

    }(jQuery));
}
```

Comment: I have a requirement to serialize somehow it before post, due to PHP's new post field limits

Comment: Well, there is still a limit regardless, it's on the post data length itself, so you might have to have to break it down to X amount of fields at a time.

Comment: Note, it is possible to change the post limits in PHP. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can

Comment: I posted an example of how to break it up into patches.

Comment: I really appreciate this, but I don't understand why this is a better solution than the one line serialize? The standard PHP post limit is 8MB, so it should easily be enough.

Comment: Well, maybe your php's limit is set lower, like I said, try without JSON.stringify and see if it works.