# Large form not posing all elements

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have a dynamically built form with ~900 check boxes in one case, and only ~755 of them are being passed to my processing page.

(Reducing the size of the form isn't an option.  It's a schedule matrix with employee down the left and shifts across the top.)

My processing code is

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
  $keys=explode("-",$key);
  if(!mysql_query("UPDATE week_schedule SET $keys[1]='$value' WHERE userid='$keys[0]'")){
    echo "<p>".$key." was not updated!</p>";
    $error=TRUE;
  }
}
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: What is the value of `count($_POST)` before the `foreach`? Is it ~755 or ~900?

Comment: see if can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can

Comment: @ShaunakKashyap It's the ~755 value.

Comment: @arilia My current max_input_vars is 1000, and I can't edit that value as I'm on a shared host

Comment: if that's the issue (the total number of your inputs is greater than 1000) so I think there's nothing you can do (unless you ask your provider to increase the value). Maybe think about using ajax to split the data in 3 or 4 requests

Answer (score 0):

What is `max_post_size` (https://www.php.net/ini.core#ini.post-max-size) in your server php.ini, perhaps you could run over it. Also, according to php manual than `$_POST` should be empty, but it worth checking anyway.

Also try to submit form using another browser to be sure that this problem is not browser-specific.

Also script may run out of `max_execution_time` while doing ≈900 database update queries.

P.S. I see from comment to the question that only ≈750 fields are passing, so maybe there is some naming issue in your form and you have some checkboxes with the same names?

Comment: post_max_size is 128M, max_execution_time is 30.

I don't think I can change these values on my shared host.

I do not have any duplicate named checkboxes.
My problem exists across all browsers. :(