# Value of Object in PHP after POST does not match what was sent via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

SO in my JavaScript i create an object which if i `console.log(data[71])` I get:

```
as_of_date
    "2014-01-31"
class_index
    "Class C"
fund_no
    13
with_load
    1
y2004
    0
y2005
    0

y2006
    0
y2007
    0
y2008
    0
y2009
    0
y2010
    "9.46%"
y2011
    "-0.20%"
y2012
    "9.91%"
y2013
    "30.48%"
```

IN my php i have a foreach that goes through each object posted:

```
    if($_POST['function'] == 'update_calendar_year') {
        $entries = $_POST['data'];
        foreach ($entries as $entry) {
            $fund_no = $entry['fund_no'];
            $y2004 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2004']);
            $y2005 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2005']);
            $y2006 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2006']);
            $y2007 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2007']);
            $y2008 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2008']);
            $y2009 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2009']);
            $y2010 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2010']);
            $y2011 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2011']);
            $y2012 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2012']);
            $y2013 = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['y2013']);
            $with_load = preg_replace('/[&%$]+/', '', $entry['with_load']);
```

When i get to the last entry the following error occurs:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: y2006 in <b>/home/diamondh/public_html/wp-content/themes/diamond-hill/functions.php</b> on line <b>69</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: y2007 in <b>/home/diamondh/public_html/wp-content/themes/diamond-hill/functions.php</b> on line <b>70</b><br />
<br />
```

If i var dump entries[71] in my PHP i get the following value:

```
array(5) {
  ["fund_no"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["class_index"]=>
  string(7) "Class C"
  ["with_load"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["y2004"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2005"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

All other passed values are correct it seems to only be the last object that gets half of its value cut off for some reason? The above var_dump should show the same value as my console.log above but does not.

In frustration i tried to pass only data[71] to my php and the value was correct:

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "functions.php",
      data: {
        function: "update_calendar_year",
        data: data[71]          
      },
      success: "success",
      dataType: "json"
    });
```

If i then check what was passed into PHP i get :

```
array(14) {
  ["fund_no"]=>
  string(2) "13"
  ["class_index"]=>
  string(7) "Class C"
  ["with_load"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["y2004"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2005"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2006"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2007"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2008"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2009"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["y2010"]=>
  string(5) "9.46%"
  ["y2011"]=>
  string(6) "-0.20%"
  ["y2012"]=>
  string(5) "9.91%"
  ["y2013"]=>
  string(6) "30.48%"
  ["as_of_date"]=>
  string(10) "2014-01-31"
}
```

Which is exactly what i would expect.

Sorry this was so long winded but this is a very odd issue and i have tried everything i could think of and have double checked what was being passed anyway i could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a limit of 1000 post fields.

You have 71 * 14 fields = 994

And then the next set of 14 fields is being cut off half way through.

Have a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can) for more information.

Either increase your max post fields, or refactor your code and UI to process fewer fields in one go.

Comment: Thank you i ahd no idea PHP had this limit. When i get into the office i will see if this works and check off your answer =)