# Posting all selected items to php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am having select control and it has more than 2000 options, here i just showing three items here for demo.

```
<select  name="Modtager[]" id="selectedOptions" size="4" multiple class="d_contact_area">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
    <option value="3">three</option>    
</select>
```

I am selecting all the value in select box and posting values to the next php page,but it is not posting all the values to the next page it stops upto 975 items when I am printing the receiver list it shows only 975 ,can any one help thanks

```
$receiver_list = array();
$receiver_list = $_POST['Modtager'];
print count($receiver_list);
```

Comment: There is no need of this line: `$receiver_list = array();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out your post size limit: `echo ini_get('post_max_size');`
If it's too small - try to change it `php_value post_max_size 20M` (php.ini)

Edit: max input vars (1000); fix:
[new limit within php: 1000 fields per POST. Does someone know, if the number can be influenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can)

Comment: Edited, this should help :)

Comment: i changed to 20m but again the receiver list shows only 975

Comment: As I said - I've edited my post - check out the second link, which has a max input vars fix.