# Sending multiple identical forms?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

So I have been looking for the past 3 days for an indication if this can be done this way. I want to create a registration page where the user picks the number of family members and then that number of forms will be displayed for the user to fill out. This can be anywhere from 1 to 10. This part is done and I can get the following result when I print the array. My question is, can I now take that information and place it in a mysql database with a record for each person?

I used this code to get the following array:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
 echo "$key=$value"."<br>";
}
```

// results of $key=$value

```
firstname0=John
lastname0=smith
years0=2011
street_address0=18 Kelly Lane
city0=test town
phone0=000 000 0000
email0=test@gmail.com
registration=15.00
pub=15.00
golf=90.00
basketball=NaN
run=10.00
hockey=10.00
banquet=25.00
ecumenical_service=1
T_shirt=20.00
Golf_shirt=
Mug=
Drinking_glass=
DVD=
Hats=
firstname1=John
lastname1=Smith2
graduated1=2014
registration1=15.00
T_shirt1=40.00
Golf_shirt1=
Mug1=
Drinking_glass1=
DVD1=
Hats1=
firstname2=Jane
lastname2=Smith3
graduated2=1990
registration2=15.00
show2=15.00
T_shirt2=
Golf_shirt2=
Mug2=
Drinking_glass2=
DVD2=
Hats2=
firstname3=Jane
lastname3=Smith Jr.
graduated3=2000
registration3=15.00
pub3=15.00
T_shirt3=
Golf_shirt3=
Mug3=
Drinking_glass3=
DVD3=
Hats3=
```

You can see that each filed name is numbered, firstname1, firstname2 and so on... So my question is can I take this array and insert it into a database or is my initial thinking of how to create multiple dynamic forms flawed?

Comment: Yes it is possible to do it, I want to ensure that your KEY has the same order and they are totally 21 keys? so I can make you example how to do it.

Comment: Or could you confirm that Hats is always your last key/field in the form?

Comment: notice [the limit of fields per POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can)

Comment: Thanks I can see that it prints the array but I wasn't sure if I could use that to get the values into the mysql table. To me it made sense but I wanted to know that it was workable.

Comment: Yes there are only 21 fields always and if they are blank they still get passed as a 0 or null value depending on the variable.

Comment: Ok I am writing a solution to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here is a workable solution, I have just test it for you and it works.

The full example here is for demonstration purpose, so you understand the concept of solving it.

You are welcome to change or modify it to full fit your requirement.

I have made this example with mysqli statement, and a dummy database, customer_info table. it is up to you change names, create database etc.

I have chosen only 3 fields to test it with, but it is expandable to unlimited fields/keys.

What is interesting for you to know is I user `array_values($data);` this turn all your keys name to numbers. to make it easier to work it this way.

you need to pass your data as array as shown in the example.

The for loop is incrementing depending on the total fields/keys.

Here is the solution:

```
<?php

$data = [
    "firstname0" => "John1",
    "lastname0"  => "Smith1",
    "years0"     => "2011",
    "firstname1" => "John2",
    "lastname1"  => "Smith2",
    "years1"     => "2012",
    "firstname2" => "John3",
    "lastname2"  => "Smith3",
    "years3"     => "2013",
    "firstname4" => "John4",
    "lastname4"  => "Smith4",
    "years4"     => "2014",
];

// this is an example of database I build modified to full fit your needs
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dummy";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

//change 3 to 21 or the total fields
$max_fields = 3;
$value = array_values($data);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($value); $i = $i + $max_fields)
{
    $value1 = $value[$i + 0];
    $value2 = $value[$i + 1];
    $value3 = $value[$i + 2];
    //add the number of fields here up to 20, that gives totally 21 fields including 0. value1 is firstname, value2 is lastname etc.
    //$value4 = $value[$i + 3];

    // this is an example of database I build modified to regarding to your database table design
    mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO customer_info
    (firstname, lastname, years)
    VALUES
    (' $value1 ', ' $value2 ', ' $value3 ')");

    echo "data is inserted in your database";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Good luck

Comment: Can I ask, you have your data array in the $data, how would I get the values out of the $_post array? I tried this method but it doesn't seem to work with $_post. Or am I doing something wrong that is fairly simple?

Comment: Not sure but it sound you are doing something wrong, are you online so can chat for a solution

Comment: Sorry I was away, I tried it, and I think what you have will work, I am just making a mistake somewhere along the line. I don't get any results but I am still working on it to see where the mistake might be. I do think that both answers here will work, I just have to find my mistake. Thanks

Comment: So I know where the mistake is, the $value = array_values($data) is not populating. $data has the information in it, but the second variable is not sowing anything. Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your form use `<input type="text" name="firstname[]" />`

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO persons VALUES(:firstname)');

foreach($registers as $key => $register){
  $stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname[$key]);
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: I have tried it using the name="firstname[]" as well as dynamically producing a number name="firstname0",1,2,3... I did this by <? echo $i; ?> as a counter. But I am unsure if either will give me results that I can use to insert into a table. I will try to the name="firstname[]" as I see how yours differs than what I was doing with it.