# Form not submitting with large amounts of data

Tags: php, forms, max

I have a web form that works like an Excel spreadsheet. Multiple rows with 8 variables for each row entry. Using a POST command, some users submit the form with 1000+ data elements. These large entries would not post, form variables weren't set, and MySQL insert statements were not being executed. Form works fine with fewer elements.

Is there a limit to the amount of data fields that can be posted in a form? I increased `max_input_vars` in `.htaccess` per user recommendation, but the edit was not getting set after running `phpinfo()`. I do not have access to `php.ini` as my site is hosted, but have requested changes/access. Also, hosted server uses suhosin. Do I also need to update `suhosin.post.max_vars`?

Comment: *Code is too complicated to post here.* - try us.

Comment: You need at least to build a simulation of your code environment, without it we can only guess.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can

Comment: It may be complicated but it'll be much easier to read that then 'imagine' it in our heads based on your description!

Comment: If it is too complicated to post then you probably need to hire someone. Without code it is too broad we could say ideas all day for why it might not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are various limits in PHP which could cause your problem. I'm not sure how many inputs you have in your form, or amount of data posted. Try looking at these:

[max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

How many input variables may be accepted. If there are more input variables than specified by this directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are truncated from the request.

[post_max_size](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Sets max size of post data allowed.

Comment: This could indeed be the issue. $_POST defaults to 1000 values. So if each of the 50 rows had 20 fields this would fill up the 1000 values.