# Ajax / PHP: Not all POST data is received

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

I am sending a nested json object via ajax (post) to my php api (using a Apache server). But I have a problem; it seems that not all data is send to my php API.

I already checked if there is any mistake in my php code but it is not. Also I get no error. So I did the following: I used

```
JSON.stringify()
```

to create manually a json file which includes my POST content. When opening the json file with php everything works fine so I think that there is trouble with the size of my post request. My manually created json file is 176 KB.

I read about the php.ini and post_max_size. So I just tried to increase it from 8 up to 16 M, restarted the server but nothing changed.

Maybe someone could help me.

The ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {api: 'save_reference_file', filename: _filenameInput,  timestamp: timeStamp, drives: dataHandler.getDriveData()},
            error: function (phpResponse) {
                console.log(phpResponse);
                onError404();
            },
            success: function (phpResponse) {
                if (phpResponse.actionsuccess === true) {
                    onSuccess();
                } else {
                    onError500();
                }
            },
        });
```

The ajax request triggers my php API which should create a json file on the server with the drives data. So no data callback is needed.

An example:
The drives array contains 183 nested objects. For testing, I counted the amount of objects which arrived to my php api. It were 34. The most data of the 34th object is not received.

```
$sended_data = $_POST['drives'];
$amound = count($sended_data);
```

PHP version: 7.2.7

Comment: Check the post data in the inspector - is everything being sent?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can

Comment: I have a php.ini-development and a php.ini-production in my php folder. The last time I edited both files to test the settings and restarted the server but nothing changed. Do I have to rename these files or something else? Maybe my editing of the files was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

[new limit within php: 1000 fields per POST. Does someone know, if the number can be influenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can)

Editing the php.ini file solved the problem. I am new to this so let me say to all other beginners: If you have a php.ini-production and php.ini-development, copy one of these files, rename it to php.ini, edit this file and restart your server. Then it will work. My (stupid) mistake was to editing both files so I had no changed.

Maybe one expert can explain the difference between this two files and when you use them.

Answer (score 1):

There are two relevant settings in your *php.ini* that need to be investigated:

- `post_max_size` - *The total size of the entire post request raw body that is acceptable*
- `max_input_vars` - *The number of individual post fields that is acceptable*

Your problem is likely one with `max_input_vars`, which defaults to a pretty low number (like 40 or something). In PHP 7+, it has a hard ceiling of 1000.

If your issue is that fields are getting truncated but the last field received is fully intact, then it is likely a problem with `max_input_vars`.

If the last field received is partial, then it is likely a problem with `post_max_size`.

---

As a matter of general practice, if you are sending in excess of 30ish post fields, they should be condensed to a stringified json value wherever possible to circumvent this issue, particularly if your code needs to remain portable and you do not have direct access to the php.ini *on all servers that it will run on*. If that is not possible, you may raise the value of `max_input_vars` in your php.ini and reboot your server to correct the issue.

Answer (score -2):

If your request take more than 30 second. Check php timeout, by default it's 30 second. You can change max_execution_time in php.ini

Comment: It does not seem that it takes that long. ~ max. 1 second til I get the server response and the json is created.

Comment: a timeout as you describe would not cause the reported problem