# Problem in post large number of nesting fields using ajax php

Tags: php, laravel, post

I am tring to submit a form using ajax with POST method.

sending parameters have nested variables with like name field[71] : [].

on try to check POST data. it is showing variable upto only 46 like field[46] => array(..).

Comment: Likely a problem with either `max_input_vars` or `max_input_nesting_level` config options. Check which values those have, and see if increasing them helps.

Comment: i have tried with max_input_vars=5000 and max_input_nesting_level=100

Comment: I would collect all html fields in one JS object then change that to JSON using JSON.parse and POST that via ajax to PHP

Comment: If your server uses the Suhosin patch (such as Apache in Debian), also add: `suhosin.get.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 5000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 5000`

Comment: i am  using jquery ajaxSubmit form function.

Comment: I mean in php.ini, just in case you server uses Suhosin patch

Comment: @syamlal Decrease ??

Comment: It would be useful to see the HTML, the Javascript and a `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Look at your Error logs, if it is anything like what others have described here, there will be a very OBVIOUS error message waiting for you to show us

Comment: _ALso check_ `post_max_size` in the `php.ini`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [new limit within php: 1000 fields per POST. Does someone know, if the number can be influenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710185/new-limit-within-php-1000-fields-per-post-does-someone-know-if-the-number-can)

Comment: increase the size of the max_input_vars in php.ini file.